# appending react components to dom element from a loop

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have a column based grid where I am trying to append thumbnails horizontally. For that, I wrote a simple loop where I fetch columns and add `Thumbnail` component to that element. Here's the code I wrote -

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.thumbnails / this.state.cols; i++)
    {
        let columns = document.getElementsByClassName('column');
        for (let i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
        {
            let element = columns.item(i)
            Object.keys(element).push(<Thumbnail href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />);
        }
    }
```

however, nothing is being pushed to the column. I am not sure how to append the react component to DOM and this experiment was a wild guess.. Can someone please help pointing out what is wrong here?

Comment: @aamirl screenshare would be a great help. are you on whereby?

Comment: okay, give me a min. connecting

Comment: thanks @aamirl for your help. sorry we could not carry on with the session.

Answer (score 0):

In React, you don't just "append" components to an arbitrary DOM element willy-nilly. From the React point of view, once DOM is rendered it is immutable and the only way to change anything is to re-render the component(s) in question.

If you absolutely have to go down the "append" route (for example, you are dealing with third party code that you cannot modify) then you should consider using jQuery or Zepto instead and modify DOM directly.

With React, you would typically do two things:

- Create a list of components (e.g. thumbnails) - often times, it would be an array
- Render the array within the parent component container

Both of these things typically happen within the parent component `render` method.

Hope that helps!